# What happens when i type perl and push enter in terminal?

Tags: linux, perl, terminal

What happens when I type `perl` and push enter in terminal?

I just did and nothing happened but what is going on behind the curtains?

If I type `python` I enter some Tron world but not when typing `perl` or maybe soon I will be surrounded by centaurs and satyrs. I will update if I am.

Comment: Happy lookout for the centaurs and satyrs ;-)

Comment: Yes I heard someone speaking in the hallway... maybe it was a lion?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The shell you are in interprets the line you've entered (performs substitutions etc.) and then executes the resulting command.  To find out what it will execute, I propose to use `type perl`.  This will show you whether the shell interprets this as an alias, a shell function or a direct command somewhere in the `$PATH`.

In your case, I assume it will execute `/usr/bin/perl`.

This program then will wait (quite silently) for input.  Perl isn't as talkative as Python because it isn't meant to be used interactively.

But you can then type `print 5`, press <kbd>Enter</kbd> and then <kbd>Ctrl-d</kbd> (the last one means "end of file").  Then you probably will see a `5` being printed, and `perl` will terminate (due to the EOF).

Comment: `__END__` has the same effect as `Ctrl-D` in such situations

Answer (score 3):

perl interpreter is expecting program from standard input,

```
perl
print 11; # hit <Ctrl+D>
11        # program executed
```